# Firestore always make 3 api calls with one taking 60 secondes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Each time I'm making a request using the Firestore library, there are 3 API calls made. One of them is taking to 60 seconds every time. I receive the data after some milliseconds, but in the network tab, I see a pending call that seems to be doing nothing.

Here's my code

```
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const getData = () => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("myCollection")
    .get();
}
```

Each time I call `getData()`, 3 API calls are made. Here's the network tab:

[image]

The request URL of the second call is: 
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects/my-project/databases/(default)`

**How can I avoid the 60s call?**

Comment: are you getting the data before? It could be some kind of long polling...

Comment: This happens every time I call Firestore, even the first time. I receive the data some milliseconds after making the call.

Comment: You can't change the way to Firestore SDK works, outside of its existing [settings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreSettings).  If you spot a problem with the way that does work, contact Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the 60s calls, I ended up calling the REST API directly without using the client library. Here's the documentation to follow to be able to make a request: [Use the Cloud Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) and [Cloud Firestore API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/)

Comment: It takes approx. 2 seconds for only first call, after that second time it works fine.... any suggestion please