# Long, additional network calls after performing Firebase Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My web application performs the following Firebase Firestore query:

```
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.5/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.5/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.5/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.5/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=false"></script>
<script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("username", "==", username).limit(1)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                //…
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //…
            });
      });
</script>
```

The single query results in 3 network calls:
[image: network call size and duration]

The first call is the query request written explicitly in my code snippet.
The third call contains `“removeTarget”:2` in the payload.

My biggest concern is this second call below that takes 1 minute to execute, sometimes being several Kilobytes in size:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel
?database=projects%2F<omitted>%2Fdatabases%2F(default)
&gsessionid=<omitted>
&VER=8
&RID=<omitted>
&SID=<omitted>
&CI=0
&AID=0
&TYPE=xmlhttp
&zx=<omitted>
&t=1
```

The GET response was an empty 200 with the following duration:

[image: network call duration]

What are these second and third calls? I am especially interested in what the second call is given the duration and size of the call.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Pierce, Every call to `.addEventListener()` adds another listener, so when the next event shows up all of the added listeners will fire. Are you sure that code is only being executed once? Is there any context you can provide or isolate that code snippet? Could you also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917121/addeventlistener-still-firing-multiple-times-even-with-same-name-callback) and see if it helps.

Comment: I confirmed with a breakpoint that the callback function provided to `addEventListener` was called once. There are no other event listeners running, the isolated code snippet above is verbatim to what produced the network calls captured in the screenshots.

Comment: Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227974/firestore-always-make-3-api-calls-with-one-taking-60-secondes) and see if it helps.

Comment: Nice find! That's the same question, and I see in the comments that Doug Stevenson is hinting at this behavior be expected. Thank you @MarcAnthonyB.